# Configure SystemJS to load imports from the same directory instead of subdir

Tags: javascript, aurelia, systemjs

I'm trying to serve Aurelia from the node_modules folder (ignoring the jspm stuff). 
I'm mapping each Aurelia module to the respective file in the node_modules folder.

```
SystemJS.config({
   baseURL: "/",
   defaultJSExtensions: true,
   transpiler: false,
   paths: {
             "aurelia-templating-resources.js/*": "../*",
          },
   map: {
            "aurelia-framework": "node_modules/aurelia-framework/dist/system/aurelia-framework.js",
            "aurelia-bootstrapper": "node_modules/aurelia-bootstrapper/dist/system/aurelia-bootstrapper.js",
            "aurelia-templating-resources": "node_modules/aurelia-templating-resources/dist/system/aurelia-templating-resources.js",
            "aurelia-templating-router": "node_modules/aurelia-templating-router/dist/system/aurelia-templating-router.js",
            ... all the other Aurelia packages
```

This works fine, except for the imports in `aurelia-templating-resources.js` and `aurelia-templating-router.js`.

Example: `aurelia-templating-resources.js` imports `compose.js` with this statement: `System.register(['./compose', ...`.

Now SystemJS tries to load this file from a subdirectory with the same name, i.e.  `aurelia-templating-resources.js/compose.js`.
But `compose.js` is in the same folder as `aurelia-templating-resources.js`.

I tried to set the path in `SystemJs.config` but this didn't work (see my example). I could of course add a map for every file but there are lots of them.

How can I configure SystemJs to load these files from the same directory instead of the subdirectory?

Comment: Why you want to ignore jspm? You should never modify `config.js` unless if you really know what you are doing (and even in this case it's not recommended)

Comment: I don't want to use it since it just doesn't work like I want. Currently I have node modules, bower components and jspm modules...

Comment: It would be easier if you use webpack skeleton https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/releases